# Get min/max from sound file (animation/sverchok nodes)

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes, sverchok

Note: this question references the same blend file here: [Sound-Driven Animation, Using Animation (and Sverchok) Nodes, is Not Working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234766/sound-driven-animation-using-animation-and-sverchok-nodes-is-not-working)

I have the following setup in animation nodes:

[image]

I am trying to get the min/max values from this sound file. I'm guessing this could be done by outputting all the values from the sound file to a list, but frankly I have no idea how to "store" these values to a list.

I am obviously using animation nodes, but transferring this data to sverchok. Would it be possible to do this in animation nodes or sverchok? Possible in both?

Blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMvKhExbVH5hSzoPK9GdetTph4r_YySM/view

Comment: I would recommend using something like audacity instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**: Using loop without storing values.

This setup gives min and max of values between frame 1 and 250:
[image]

**Method 2:** Storing values as text.

This script creates a text block containing values in frame range.

```
import bpy

# settings
frame_start = 1
frame_end = 250
node_tree_name = "NodeTree"
data_interface_name = "Data Interface"
text_block_name = "my_data"
separator = "\n"

# create/get text block
text_block = bpy.data.texts.get(text_block_name)
if text_block is None:
    text_block = bpy.data.texts.new(name = text_block_name)
    
# clear existing
text_block.clear()  

for i in range(frame_start, frame_end + 1):
    # set frame
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
    
    # get value from animation nodes
    value = bpy.data.node_groups[node_tree_name].nodes[data_interface_name].getValue()
    
    # convert value to string
    string = str(value)
    if i != frame_end: string += separator
        
    # write value to text block
    text_block.write(string)
```

Before running this script use Data interface node to export value.
[image]

The script will generate a text block something like this:
[image]

We can convert text data into float by this expression
[image]

Final node tree
[image]

Comment: Thanks Hari, both of these methods worked! I went with the 2nd method, as the list of values is most helpful for my use. I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 1):

i hope i did understand your right, and here is how you can store values in a list which you can "load/get" at any frame.

In my example i generate a random float list for every frame, get the max value and store this in a list.

[image]

result:

frame 1:

[image]

frame 2: (and so on)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, this worked! I should've explained myself better, but didn't even realize when asking the question, that a list of all the values is actually the most helpful for my case.

Comment: Glad I could help!