# Using Sound File to Drive Animation in Sverchok Nodes

Tags: animation, drivers, audio, sverchok

Is there a way to use a sound file inside of the Sverchok addon?

I am trying to use the output of a sound file to drive an animation in Sverchok, but cannot figure out how to link the sound file into the Sverchok node interface.

I am essentially trying to copy the process used in [this tutorial](https://www.blendernation.com/2014/04/03/using-sound-to-drive-animation-in-blender/), where a sound file is used as a driver to affect an object's properties. I followed this tutorial easily enough, and could even add the driver to a value node in the Shader Editor to control an object's color. However, using the same process, I cannot add the driver to nodes inside Sverchok. I also tried getting the object's properties (in this case rotation, which is being driven by the sound file), but this does not seem to update in Sverchok with frame changes:

[image]

In the past I've gotten the output of a sound file into Sverchok via animation nodes ([this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238494/get-min-max-from-sound-file-animation-sverchok-nodes) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234766/sound-driven-animation-using-animation-and-sverchok-nodes-is-not-working) post). Unfortunately, I've since started working on a new computer and cannot install animation nodes.

This blend file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1adnwXv0ssqzfnwNnV5PfdGBKxIEzn8i7/view?usp=sharing) as well.

I am also using Sverchok version 1.1.0 with Blender version 3.1.2.

Comment: @Chris - if you are still interested, check out the answer below, worked well for me

Comment: Nice!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a good workflow to achieve this, which is still pretty much the same as what is shown in the first few minutes of this video: https://www.blendernation.com/2014/04/03/using-sound-to-drive-animation-in-blender/

1. Add an object
2. Create a custom property for this object, make sure to increase the max value to something large, like 10,000

[image]

3. Insert a keyframe on this custom property (with the current frame set to 1)
4. Open the graph editor with the object selected, you should see the custom property there. Select Key > Bake Sound to F-Curves > select your sound file
5. Add a driver to your object's location, rotation, or scale
6. Edit the driver properties, change the driver type to Single Property, add your object to the Prop section, and add the custom variable data path to the Path section
   [image]
7. You can now get the sound value from a node setup in sverchok like this:

[image]

blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOkLNpoSbPhQ0zHhVpXeId1upZjZoWlG/view?usp=sharing